# ¿Cómo hacer una migración de laravel elocuente con relaciones a la misma tabla?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, table, relaciones, migration

si en lugar de tener una tabla de users donde un usuario puede seguir a muchos usuarios. Tuviera una tabla cows donde cada vaca tiene un único padre y una única madre, donde las vacas padres pueden tener muchos hijos. ¿requiero una tabla externa para almacenar eso o puedo simplemente añadir en mi tabla cows los campos cow_father_id y cow_mother_id?

- me refiero a hacer 2 relaciones elocuentes de la tabla cows con la misma tabla cows

**y cómo sería esta migración?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buen día,

Si es posible hacerlo con una sola tabla y las relaciones serían también en un solo modelo, no sé muy bien que datos necesites en tu tabla pero podría ser algo así

Migración:

```
Schema::create('cows', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->foreignId('father_id')->nullable();
    $table->foreignId('mother_id')->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Tu modelo tendría que tener las siguientes relaciones:

```
public function father()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Cow::class, 'father_id');
}
public function mother()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Cow::class, 'mother_id');
}
public function calf()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Cow::class);
}
```

Comment: [^_^] - Gracias, justo lo que necesitaba.