# Relacionar un Modelo consigo mismo

Tags: laravel, relaciones, modelos

mi problema es el siguiente:

Tengo un proyecto con laravel y necesito que los usuarios puedan tener uno de los 3 roles siguientes: admin, supervisor o comercial.

He creado los roles con Spatie, y los he asignado mediante un Controlador personalizado pero mediante el Modelo Users, ya que necesito que tengan acceso al login y que sean usuarios.

El problema es que ahora necesito relacionar el supervisor con los comerciales en relacion 1N (un supervisor contiene muchos revisores) y 1:1 (un comercial tiene un supervisor), pero no se como hacerlo porque ambos pertenecen a la misma tabla.

**UserController**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

class UserController extends Controller
{

    public function adminDashboard () {
        return view ('User.Admin.dashboard');
    }
    public function supervisorDashboard () {
        return view ('User.Supervisor.dashboard');
    }
    public function comercialDashboard () {
        return view ('User.Comercial.dashboard');
    }

    public function FormSupervisor() {
        return view('User.Supervisor.create');
    }
    
    public function FormComercial() {
        return view('User.Supervisor.create');
    }
    
    /** Creando SUPERVISOR
     *  Asignando el rol mediante Spatie
    */
    public function StoreSupervisor(Request $request) {
        User::create([
            'name' => $request['name'],
            'firstname' => $request['firstname'],
            'lastname' => $request['lastname'],
            'email' => $request['email'],
            'document' => $request['document'],
            'phonenumber' => $request['phonenumber'],
            'birth' => $request['birth'],
            'address' => $request['address'],
            'password' => Hash::make($request['password']),
        ])->assignRole('supervisor');

        return back()->with('success', 'usuario creado correctamente');
    }

    /** Creando COMERCIAL
     *  Asignando el rol mediante Spatie
    */
    public function StoreComercial(Request $request) {
        User::create([
            'name' => $request['name'],
            'firstname' => $request['firstname'],
            'lastname' => $request['lastname'],
            'email' => $request['email'],
            'document' => $request['document'],
            'phonenumber' => $request['phonenumber'],
            'birth' => $request['birth'],
            'address' => $request['address'],
            'password' => Hash::make($request['password']),
        ])->assignRole('comercial');

        return back()->with('success', 'usuario creado correctamente');
    }
}
```

[image: model_has_roles]

[image: roles]

Espero que puedan ayudarme, muchas gracias!

Comment: Fijate si te sirve esto https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/516626/c%c3%b3mo-hacer-una-migraci%c3%b3n-de-laravel-elocuente-con-relaciones-a-la-misma-tabla

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La tabla de usuarios necesita un campo para referenciar el id del superior directo, y no puede tener, en ese campo, un valor que no exista en la tabla de usuarios.

Tal como aparece en el enlace compartido por [@porloscerros](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/92278/porloscerros-%CE%A8), una tabla puede autorreferenciarse así que, mediante una migración como la siguiente:

```
Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->foreignId('superior_id') 
        ->constrained('users')  
        ->nullable() 
        ->onDelete('SET NULL'); 
});
```

**Nota**: originalmente la migración que sugerí tenía un error. Ver la explicación al pie de esta respuesta.

Y dos relaciones declaradas en el modelo como

```
public function superior() {
   return $this->belongsTo(self, 'superior_id', 'id');
}

public function subalternos() {
   return $this->hasManu(self, 'superior_id', 'id');
}
```

Podrías obtener, para cada usuario, ya sea su superior directo como sus subalternos.

```
 $user = User::with(['superior','subalternos'])->findOrfail($request->id);
```

Teniendo siempre presente que un comercial aparecerá sin subalternos, y un supervisor sin superior directo.

**Caveat**: Aunque lo ideal sería impedir que un comercial tenga como superior a alguien que no ostenta el rol de supervisor, no creo que ésto se pueda hacer sólo a punta de llaves foráneas. Por otro lado, entiendo que tampoco puedes impedir que un usuario tenga varios roles si adoptas el paquete Spatie Permission tal como viene. Podrías, a lo mejor, tener un campo `role_id` y declarar la relación

```
public function rol() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Role::class);
}
```

Y en [un mutator](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators) hacer esa verificación. ¿Vale la pena? Suena como mucho trabajo para una solución muy sui generis.

**Bonus Track:** Aunque no lo estás preguntando, si en algún momento te surgiera la necesidad de añadir más peldaños a la jerarquía empresarial, puedes usar un [scope](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#query-scopes) para generar un query "telescópico"_

```
  public function scopeConSubordinados($query) {

       return $query->with(['subordinados' => fn($q) => $q->con_subordinados()]);
  }
```

Cuyo efecto sería traer tu subordinados, y por cada uno sus subordinados, y por cada uno de ellos etc etc hasta llegar a un peldaño sin subordinados.

```
 $user = User::con_subordinados()->findOrFail($request->id);
```

El scope para obtener recursivamente tu superior y su superior y así hasta llegar a Chuck Norris, supongo, es prácticamente lo mismo pero cambiando `subordinados` por `superior`.

---

**Errata**

originalmente la migración que sugerí tenía un error que el mismo OP [EmilioVM](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/290810/emiliovm) me hizo notar. En ella decía

```
    $table->foreignId('superior_id') 
        ->constrained()
        -> etc etc
```

Esto es equivalente a crear un campo de tipo UNSIGNED BIGINT llamado `superior_id` más una llave foránea que referencie el campo `id` de la inexistente tabla `superiors`.

Eso no tenía por dónde funcionar, y no adapté correctamente el ejemplo de [la documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints). Gracias Emilio, me recordaste que no hay maestro que no pueda ser alumno.

Comment: Magnifica respuesta. Por cierto dentro en el `constrained()`, he añadido `users`, quedando `constrained('users')`, porque de lo contrario me daba error en las migraciones. ¿Estaría bien hecho?

Comment: Aah, tienes razón. Voy a editar la respuesta.

Comment: Una pregunta más, disculpa las molestias. Cuando trato de mostrar el superior_id en blade al usuario de sesión, con `Auth::user()->superior_id`, me delvuelve el `id` correctamente, pero si quiero el nombre poniendo `Auth::user()->superior_id->name` me devuelve error: `Attempt to read property "name" on int`. ¿Como podría ver la información de la tabla relacionada en blade?

Comment: Sería `user()->superior->name`. La propiedad `superior` referencia una instancia de User (el usuario que supervisa al actual), mientras que superior_id es sólo un campo que Eloquent usa por debajo para hacer el join