# problema attach tabla pivot laravel

Tags: laravel, base-de-datos, eloquent, relaciones, pivot

el tema es el siguiente. Tengo un modelo `users`, el cual quiero relacionar entre sí, haciendo que *un usuario comercial pueda tener muchos supervisores, y un usuario supervisor pueda tener muchos comerciales*. Para ello he creado una migración llamada `user_user`con los campos siguientes:

```
Schema::create('user_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignId('supervisor_id') 
                    ->nullable() 
                    ->constrained('users')  
                    ->onDelete('SET NULL');
            $table->foreignId('comercial_id') 
                    ->nullable() 
                    ->constrained('users')  
                    ->onDelete('SET NULL');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

[image: diagrama relacion usuarios]
también modifiqué el modelo `User` para realizar las relaciones de la siguiente manera:

**User.php**

```
 public function supervisors () {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class,'user_user', 'supervisor_id','user_id');
    }

    public function comercials () {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class,'user_user', 'comercial_id','user_id');
    }
```

Si trato de realizar las relaciones con tinker en la base de datos, referencia correctamente los `id` en la tabla `users`, pero no funciona el método `attach`. Al tratar de utilizarlo para asignarle un id a un usuario me salta el siguiente error:

[image: error attach]

aquí llamando solamente a `comercials`

[image: comercials]

¿como podría hacer para añadir los datos en la tabla?

¿Y en el controlador, cual sería la mejor manera de añadir los datos en la tabla pivot?

Muchas gracias

Comment: Pero... no entiendo para qué necesitas el pivote. Debiera ser suficiente con el campo `supervisor_id` para declarar la relación `belongsTo`, y su existencia necesariamente implica la relación inversa `hasMany`. A menos que quieras permitir que un comercial reporte a más de un supervisor, ese pivote sólo te está complicando la vida

Comment: Gracias por tu sugerencia. ¿Quieres decir que podría añadir un campo en ```users```y llamarlo ```supervisor_id```, al cual cada usuario que haga referencia a un supervisor le añada el id del supervisor dentro del campo? o ¿como lo harías?

Comment: En la otra pregunta (https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/557042/relacionar-un-modelo-consigo-mismo/557394#557394) se podría usar `supervisor_id` donde yo puse `superior_id`. El nombre que sugerí fue pensando en una solución genérica para representar un organigrama cualquiera

Comment: Tenéis razón, utilice la repuesta de @ffflabs sobre la autoreferencia y traté de crear una tabla pivot para la relación, cuando lo más óptimo es lo que comentáis vosotros. Volveré. A realizar las relaciones sin pivot. Muchas gracias 